# record streaming file from the MediaElement

Tags: c#, windows-8, app-store, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am working on Windows 8.1 app and I have this radio channel that i wanna stream and play it in "Media Element" this is easy but I wanna be able to save the playing stream to the hard-disk in the real time thank you! .

Comment: Please share what you achieve so far.

Comment: i have just  mediaelement with direct url to the source